# when there is no data in my json file that time my component didn't display

Tags: reactjs, json, components

This is my Table.js file code.
In this component i pass `UserData` which hold data that come from the server, `handleEditButton` method for update my data and `handleDeleteButton` for delete my data. When `UserData` is empty than i'm return "No data found" other wise it's show's data in tabular format

```
const Table = ({ UserData, handleEditButton, handleDeleteButton }) => {
  if (UserData == '') {
    return (
      <>
        {
           <h2>N Data Found</h2>
        }
      </>
    )
  }
  else {
    return (
      <>
        {
          <table cellSpacing={0} cellPadding={0} className={tableStyles.details}>

            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th className={tableStyles.table}>Id</th>
                <th className={tableStyles.table}>Name</th>
                <th className={tableStyles.table}>Address</th>
                <th className={tableStyles.table}>E-mail</th>
                <th className={tableStyles.table}>Mobile No</th>
                <th className={tableStyles.table}>Gender</th>
                <th className={tableStyles.table}>City</th>
                <th className={tableStyles.table}>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              {
                (UserData &&  UserData.map((user) => (
                  <tr>
                    <th key={user.id}>{user.id}</th>
                    <td className={tableStyles.name}>{user.name}</td>
                    <td className={tableStyles.address}>{user.address}</td>
                    <td className={tableStyles.mail}>{user.mail}</td>
                    <td>{user.no}</td>
                    <td>{user.gender}</td>
                    <td>{user.city}</td>
                    <td colSpan={2} className={tableStyles.btnGroup}>
                      <button className={tableStyles.editBtn} onClick={(e) => { handleEditButton(user.id) }}>Edit</button>
                      <button className={tableStyles.deleteBtn} onClick={(e) => { handleDeleteButton(user.id) }}>Delete</button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                )))
               
              }
            </tbody>

          </table>

        }
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `UserData` is `""`? or can you provide a snippet for a `console.log(UserData)` before your `if` block

Comment: Yeah I agree with @ETCasual, we need to see what `UserData` is. It might be undefined or something else

Answer (score 0):

You missed adding a ternary condition.
You can check with the following code.

```
    const Table = ({ UserData, handleEditButton, handleDeleteButton }) => {
{
UserData == "" ? (
<h2>No Data Found</h2>
) : (
<table cellSpacing={0} cellPadding={0} className={tableStyles.details}>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th className={tableStyles.table}>Id</th>
    <th className={tableStyles.table}>Name</th>
    <th className={tableStyles.table}>Address</th>
    <th className={tableStyles.table}>E-mail</th>
    <th className={tableStyles.table}>Mobile No</th>
    <th className={tableStyles.table}>Gender</th>
    <th className={tableStyles.table}>City</th>
    <th className={tableStyles.table}>Action</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  {UserData &&
    UserData.map((user) => (
      <tr>
        <th key={user.id}>{user.id}</th>
        <td className={tableStyles.name}>{user.name}</td>
        <td className={tableStyles.address}>{user.address}</td>
        <td className={tableStyles.mail}>{user.mail}</td>
        <td>{user.no}</td>
        <td>{user.gender}</td>
        <td>{user.city}</td>
        <td colSpan={2} className={tableStyles.btnGroup}>
          <button
            className={tableStyles.editBtn}
            onClick={(e) => {
              handleEditButton(user.id);
            }}
          >
            Edit
          </button>
          <button
            className={tableStyles.deleteBtn}
            onClick={(e) => {
              handleDeleteButton(user.id);
            }}
          >
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ))}
</tbody>
</table>
);
}
};
```